# 画像URLを保存せずに縮小したいです

Tags: php

画像縮小で検索すると下記のようなコードで縮小できるそうですが、この場合PHPを画像として表示させています。

```
// コンテンツがPNG画像であることをブラウザにお知らせ
header ('Content-Type: image/png');

// オリジナル画像のファイルパスを指定
$org_file = 'images/sakura.png';

list($org_w, $org_h) = getimagesize($org_file);

// 拡大するサイズを指定
$copy_w = $org_w*2;
$copy_h = $org_h*2;

// オリジナルファイルの画像リソース
$org_img = imagecreatefrompng($org_file);

// コピー画像のリソース
$copy_img = imagecreatetruecolor($copy_w, $copy_h);

// リサイズ
imagecopyresized($copy_img, $org_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $copy_w, $copy_h, $org_w, $org_h);

// 拡大したコピー画像を表示
imagepng($copy_img);

// 画像リソースを破棄
imagedestroy($org_img);
imagedestroy($copy_img);
```

そうではなくて、画像URLを保存せず縮小してAWSにアップロードすることは不可能ですか？アップロードはSDKを使ってできています。

---

説明不足だったので追記します

```
// これだと成功する
$source = "http://image.jpg";

// 本当はこうしたいです。当然エラーになります。$copy_imgは上で作った縮小された画像
$source = imageJpeg($copy_img);


$uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3client, $source, [
         'bucket' => 'bucket1',
         'key'    => "{$num}.jpg",
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

サンプルに挙げられているコードはphpですので、すでにサーバにアップロードされた画像について縮小処理をしているものです。$copy_imgをファイルに書き出せば縮小画像が保存されますが、画像をアップロードする前に、縮小してから送信したい、ということでしょうか？

だとすると、phpではなく、JavaScriptで組むしかないのではないかと思います。